# How to test for injectiveness of a function with two variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know how to check for the invectiveness of a function such as f(x) = x + 5. I just use the fact that for injectiveness, f(x) = f(y) implies x=y. But how can a function such as the function f : Z^2 → Q with $f(x,y) = 2^x3^y$ be handled? How can you check whether or not that function is injective? What is the methodology?

Comment: Use the fact that for injectiveness, $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$ implies $(x,y)=(x',y')$ i.e. $x=x'$ and $y=y'$. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is injective if $f(x, y) = f(u, v) \Rightarrow (x, y) = (u, v)$.
[And $(x, y) = (u, v)$ if and only if $x = u$ and $y = v$]

For example, the function $f: \mathbb{Z^2} \to \mathbb{Q}$ with $f(x, y) = 2^x3^y$ that you've defined is injective. For $f(x, y) = f(u, v) \Rightarrow 2^x3^y = 2^u3^v \Rightarrow 2^{x - u} = 3^{v-y}$ which is possible only when $x - u = v - y = 0$, given that $x, y, u, v \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $x = u,\ y = v$.

Comment: I think the OP means $2^x3^y$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Oh, that makes much more sense, thank you!